# Как объединить 2 метки?

Tags: поддержка, метки

Как объединить 2 метки, если у меня ещё нет ни одного ответа по ним?

Например, эти [слияние](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [merge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge)

Comment: А зачем? Если вы только что сами предложили вторую разнести по другим меткам.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight хочется подмёрджить одну метку к дургой. Т.е. выпиливаем из всех впоросов упоминание метки. А прицпеляем одну метку к другой

Comment: Если выпилить из всех вопросов, метка просто испарится через день. Объединять будет нечего, да и не нужно, если метка бессмысленная.

Answer (score 4):

Классическая схема "спаривания" меток заключается в предложении синонима метки. [Пример страницы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/synonyms). Но для этого надо иметь рейтинг 5+ по основной метке (т.е. давать полезные ответы на вопросы по этой метке). После этого начинается голосование за синоним и другие участники с опытом ответов по той метке могут проголосовать.

Когда опыта позитивных ответов по метке нет, но тем не менее хочется объединить её с какой-то другой, прямой путь - создание соответствующего вопроса на Мете с метками [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) [синонимы-меток](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba). В вопросе нужно описать почему вы считаете, что такое объединение действительно нужно. Если вопрос вызовет интерес сообщества, то могут как найтись участники с достаточным рейтингом по метке, чтобы инициировать голосование о синониме, или даже модератор может провести синонимизацию по быстрой схеме.